# Screen: "Cannot exec /my/path/to/zsh" with local shell

Tags: zsh, gnu-screen

Whenever I try to run screen under a Zsh shell that I compiled under my home directory, I get the following error:

```
> screen
Cannot exec '/my/path/to/zsh/bin/zsh'
```

The Z shell is perfectly functional, and I have verified that I can run screen if I invoke it using a system shell (e.g. `csh`). I usually get into `zsh` with: `exec zsh`. Here is some additional info about my system:

```
> echo $SHELL
/my/path/to/zsh/bin/zsh

> echo $ZSH_VERSION
5.0.0

> which screen
/usr/bin/screen

> screen --version
Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct
```

My `.screenrc` just has two lines in it:

```
escape ^A^A
bind o other
```

In case it matters: `/my/path/to/zsh/` refers figuratively  to a path under my home directory.

### Update

1. Output of calling `file`:

   > ```
   > > file /my/path/to/zsh/bin/zsh
   > > /~/sw/zsh/bin/zsh: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for
   > > GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), 
   > > for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped
   > ```
2. But I **can** successfully run `/my/path/to/zsh/bin/zsh` and enter `zsh` from my `csh` shell. I usually switch to zsh with `exec /my/path/to/zsh/bin/zsh`
3. Below are the `ls` details on `/my/path/to/zsh/bin/zsh`

   > ```
   > -rwxr-xr-x 2 YYYY ZZZZ 651K Jan 3 11:58 zsh*
   > ```
4. Mi `.login`  is empty (it only has comments on it)
5. I don't have a `.profile` file
6. `cat/etc/*-release`:

   > ```
   > Scientific Linux SL release 5.1 (Boron)
   > ```

Any thoughts on what may be causing this and how to get screen to work with my local installation of `zsh`?

Comment: Can you execute `/my/path/to/zsh/bin/zsh` otherwise (with full path)? Is `/my/path/to/zsh/bin/zsh` by any chance a wrapper script with no she-bang line or an invalid she-bang line?

Comment: You should start screen through strace to understand what's going on: `strace -f -o screen.strace screen

Comment: Please post the output of `file /my/path/to/zsh/bin/zsh` and `ls -l /my/path/to/zsh/bin/zsh /usr/bin/screen`. Are you setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` anywhere? Is this a 32-bit or 64-bit installation, or mixed?

Comment: If the path is `my/path/to/zsh/bin/zsh` in your home, it has to be `/home/you-the-user/my/path/to/zsh/bin/zsh`. If you give a path to a file starting with `/` that starts at `/`, always. If it doesn't start with `/`, it starts at the current directory (`~` expands to the home of the user, so an alternative could be `~/my/path/to/zsh/bin/zsh`.

Comment: What you report for `file /my/path/to/zsh/bin/zsh` and `ls -l /my/path/to/zsh/bin/zsh` are inconsistent. Please copy-paste the real session transcripts, and provide more information about your environment: processor type, unix variant, distribution, anything peculiar about your installation; also how you configured and installed zsh, and anything relevant in your `.login`, `.profile`, `.cshrc`, `.zshrc` (if in doubt, post everything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarrassing:  the value of of my `$SHELL` variable was not correct (it had a typo). I apologize - I will make sure I triple check these things before posting a question like this and wasting everyone's time. Thanks so much to all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

One possible reason is that `screen` is privileged (on some systems, it's setgid `utmp`, to be able to log terminal ownership to the [`utmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/utmp) file), and that this zsh binary needs a library that isn't in the default library path. Calling a setuid or setgid program erases some environment variables, in particular `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

If you can execute `/my/path/to/zsh/bin/zsh` from outside screen but not from inside, and you're setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your `.profile`, that would explain your symptoms.

Comment: Thanks Gilles. I have updated my OP with more info. As a matter of fact, I am manually adding some paths to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` both in my `.zshrc`  and `.cshrc` files, and I need them to be there for other reasons, although I typically switch to `zsh` with `exec /my/path/to/zsh/bin/zsh`, so I am not sure if my definitions in `.cshrc` carry over to `zsh`. Is there anything I can do knowing this?